# Timing issue while writing mocha test cases

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to write a test case for one of my REST Apis using mocha.

My Rest api looks like this:

```
server.route({
    method : "DELETE",
    path   : "/local/{id}",

    handler: function (request, reply) {
        var id = request.params.id;
        return getId(id)
        .then(function (result) {
            return testFunction(result, id, reply);
        })
        .catch (function (err) {
            reply(400).err;
        })
    }

    function testFunction(result, id, reply) {
        return update(id, result)
        .then(function (resp) {
            reply(resp);
            stopSomething(id)
            .then(function () {
                //do some work
                return Bluebird.resolve(data);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                //handle error & just log..user does not need to know
                //stopSomething is a promise chain which runs in background
            });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            //handle error and reply to user
        });
    }
});
```

To test this I wrote the following test case:

```
describe("with an valid id", function () {
    var stopSomethingStub;
    var result
    before(function () {
        stopSomethingStub = Sinon.stub(stopSomethinbObject, "stopSomething", function () {
            return Bluebird.resolve();
        });
        return new Request("DELETE", "/local/id123").inject(server)
        .then(function (data) {
            result = data;
        });
    });
    after(function () {
        //do clean up of stubs
    });

    it("deletes id", function () {
        expect(result.statusCode).to.equal(200);
        expect(stopSomethingStub.called).to.be.true;
        //Few more checks
    });
}
```

Right now, the "it" block executes immediately after receiving the 200 Ok response for the DELETE Request. However I would like it to finish the entire promise chain before checking the assertion. stopSOmethingStub.called is shown as false if I keep it as the first expect block. However if I keep it as the last assertion it works. I think this is some timing issue.

Comment: Try `return stopSomething(id).then(...).catch(...)` in `testFunction()`

Comment: @robertklep Tried that before. Did not work.

Comment: Sounds like it's time for an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).